# Screenshot in Android phone without rooting

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, screenshot, framebuffer

I want to get screenshot at any instant, suppose if user press menu button so that current screenshot could be taken and saved in SD Card . I searched alot and came with these conslusions

- The apps present on Google Play need your phone to be rooted, the apps that claim they can work without being rooted have 1.0 star rating and worst reviews
- We need to access the frame buffer and there is no API that provides that
- Every phone provides its own way like Press Menu + Vol to get screenshot, invoke such call.(least usefull as there are new technologies coming everyday)

So should I suppose that this is not possible

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programatically take a screenshot on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android)

Comment: @still_learning I go through this question as well, it is not solved the images is from your own app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So should I suppose that this is not possible

Correct. Apps cannot take screenshots of other apps, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Generally there is a take a screen shot button on most phones - on mine I believe it is the down button and power button pressed together.  Why wouldn't you just allow the users to utilize the built in screen shot method and utilize the gallery?  CommonsWare has it right - privacy/security reasons are pretty obvious here.

Comment: @CommonsWare that sounds like an answer

Comment: @NathanielWaggoner I have android phone with 5'' LCD, I press Power plus - Volume at same time to get the screenshot. with such a large screen I look like a complete fool doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may [take screenshot on Android](http://www.transphone.net/android-transfer/take-screenshot-on-android.html) by using an app called [Android Transfer](http://www.transphone.net/android-transfer.html).
It allows you to save your screenshot on the computer at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Two things we need to fix

1. Root your Phone(Android version, brand, CSC, PDA?)
2. How to take screenshot without manual operations

Rooting method we can find on XDA forums, or you can try [Kingo Android Root](http://www.kingoapp.com), i root with my Galaxy S4. After rooting our phone, we can download apps from Google play which allow us to capture screenshot.

Use Android manager apps on your PC, so many of them. I'm sure they all built in with screenshot functions. And [transfer screenshot to PC](http://www.iphone-to-android.com/android-transfer.htm) you nee a Android file transfer.